# How to avoid black screen while invoking another activity in android?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-alertdialog

i am invoking an activity using intent from main activity. But during the invocation few system dialog boxes are displayed because of which a black screen is displayed. How can i avoid such black screen.

Comment: how do you invoke another activity? Any sample code

Comment: I am configuring WIFI setting before invoking second activity. Now when i launch intent for another activity few dialog box pops-up and behind these dialog boxes black screen of my second activity is displayed.

Comment: you can avoid this by adding your dialog box in runOnUiThread method

Comment: These dialogs are system generated. I have no control over them, as i said i am doing some wifi configuration changes after which these dialog boxes are displayed by the system.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Please check the flags you are setting in your intent.

If you have a finish(); or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK - a blank screen may show up on pre ICS devices as the current activity has been cleared before another activity is started.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
```

Comment: Hi, i used @android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar this solves the issue but there is a little flicker when two dialog boxes are shown one after another. Even though i am using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

Comment: Try adding overridePendingTransition (0, 0); below startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to finish the current activity during switching to other, call finish() after startActivity() method.

Checkout any long running or heavy tasks under the onCreate() method of new activity, it will block the activity onload untill the tasks has been finish.

Also check some transition properties ot other window flags these may also be the reasons in some cases.