# How to avoid black screen on startActivity when FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is set?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, flags

I am launching a new activity using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

While `MyNewActivity` is launching, a black screen is shown.

If I remove `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, the activity is launched without showing a black screen at any moment (instead, the previous activity is shown while the new one loads).

Is there any way to avoid this black screen? Removing the flags seems to not be an option (I need to clear all the current task's stack and launch a new activity as the root one).

**EDIT:** I attach a very simple code which reproduces the issue (set a dark theme such as `Theme.AppCompat` for the app). The black screen is shown for very little time (depends on how many work the receiving activity does when launching), but you can see it. If you don't use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`, the black screen is not shown and the transition is smooth:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyNewActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**MyNewActivity**

```
public class MyNewActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK ME!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_new.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am the new activity!" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fix your app so that it doesn't do a lot in `onCreate()`. Offload the stuff into a background thread that you start in `onCreate()` instead.

Comment: I can't optimize it anymore, unfortunately (the app has some very special visual design guidelines which require doing some handling of background images in the main thread). Anyway, that's **not** the problem. I have attached sample code to reproduce it on any project, even with an activity that does nothing.

Comment: Another option would be to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` instead of `CLEAR_TASK`. This will only work if you leave the original instance of `MyNewActivity` in the stack (ie: don't finish it when you launch other Activities). If this still doesn't fix it, you can try `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. This will clear all other activities off the stack and return to the existing instance of `MyNewActivity`. In this case, you could add an "extra" to the `Intent`, which `MyNewActivity` can check in `onNewIntent()` and if set, it could reinitialize itself.

Comment: I have already checked the other `Intent` launch modes, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is not useful in my case as I could have never launched `MyNewActivity`, and I want to clear all the previous activity stack.

For example, I have the following flow:
`A`->`B`->`C`->`D`->`MyNewActivity`

I want to erase from my activity stack the `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` activities, and launch `MyNewActivity`. The only flag that does what I want is `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. At least, that is the only one I'm aware of.

Comment: You should delete `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`  and instead call `finish()` after starting new activity. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501213/how-to-avoid-black-screen-while-invoking-another-activity-in-android) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To completely avoid the "black screen" (aka "preview") you can add the following to your `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

However a better approach is do less things on main thread during `Activity.onCreate` and let show the preview screen while user is waiting. 
For a smooth transition, you can set a custom background to your windows adding this to your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/slash_screen</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I never thought that what was being displayed was the preview!