# How to avoid black screen when Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is set?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my android app, I need to use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` to set my intent flag. I can remove all my previous `Activities` and start a new `Activity` in this way.This is my code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Gerenxinxi.this, MainPart.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

However,I found a flicker of black screen when i use the code above. If I don't set intent flag with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` , the flicker of black screen will be gone.My question is: what can I do to avoid the black screen when `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is set ?

Before I write down this question, I have found that someone has the similar question.This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015885/how-to-avoid-black-screen-on-startactivity-when-flag-activity-clear-task-is-set) However,the answers of this question can not solve my problem.So I ask the question again.I hope anyone can help me.Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried putting overridePendingTransition(0,0); before finish()?

Comment: i have tried this before,the black screen still exists.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This initial screen that you see is called the "Preview" screen. You can disable this completely by declaring this in your theme:

```
android:windowDisablePreview

<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <!-- This disables the black preview screen -->
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i will try your way at once~

Comment: Prefect solution , thnx budy

Answer (score 0):

only one solution i found it instead of showing black screen show app theme background. in my case its white

```
     <application

            android:name="com.my.MyApplication"

            android:allowBackup="true"

            android:icon="@drawable/launcher"

            android:label="@string/app_name"

            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme”>


   <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <!-- This disables the black preview screen -->
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i will try your way at once~

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Gerenxinxi.this, MainPart.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i have tried your solution, but the black screen still exists. Darshan Mistry's answer may solve it.

Comment: Are you testing on a slow device or recent ones?

Comment: an android phone which system is  Android OS 4.2 and it is not a slow device.

Comment: The code that Darshan might do the job. I'm not wrong the black screen occurs because of the Zygote/Android app process.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your style

```
android:windowDisablePreview = true.
```