# Black screen appearing for 1 sec while moving from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

An array with 3 values is moved to 2nd activity from first. And the 2nd activity is shown using timer thread from 1st one. This is what done

Not sure what is the reason behind black screen. Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you work heavy operation on `UI` thread?

Comment: My Log cat shows this message :
The application may be doing too much on its main thread.
What can be reason behind this and how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

[How to avoid black screen when Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264157/how-to-avoid-black-screen-when-intent-flag-activity-new-task-intent-flag-activ/31264611#31264611)

please see above link in which i have to give answer of your question.

Comment: After adding that line. I see white screen color instead of black screen.