# Activity black screen issue

Tags: android, android-activity

While switching activities I am getting black screen in between the activities.

Here is my code.

```
Intent main = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(main);
```

Comment: after removing `main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` will perfectly fine?

Comment: The issue not because of this code...can you share entire code or share logcat information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid black screen while invoking another activity in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501213/how-to-avoid-black-screen-while-invoking-another-activity-in-android)

Comment: that is not coming every time,

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your code with this**

```
Intent main = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(main);
overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
```

> ints you are provide for overridePendingTransition(int enterAnim, int
>   exitAnim) correspond to the two animations - removing the old Activity
>   and adding the new one.