# How to avoid black screen while startActivity using Intent?

Tags: android

in my app, I have activity A and activity B (show as a dialog), when I startActivity B from A, it's ok. Problem is when I finish B and start activity A again (close dialog B), a black screen display shortly.

I have search and found that way https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504110/6112421. This prevent the black screen display, but activity A will create another instance.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QC.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition (0, 0);
finish();
```

If I add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to prevent from creating new instance, the black screen display again.
How to combine two things here, avoid black screen and just one instance of A.
Thank for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app theme, you can add this line

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Comment: I tried, but didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling the app them in application tag in the Manifests file

Comment: Oh gosh! My mistake. It's work now! Thanks!!!

Comment: have a nice day :)